# Problema usando el metodo isMember de CriteriaBuilder con Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, spring-boot, jpa, maven, criteria-api

Al utilizar el metodo isMember de CriteriaBuilder con Kotlin en mi aplicacion me da el siguiente error en la siguiente linea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve investigando y siempre usan esa forma para agregar un predicado para filtrar cuando se neceista filtrar por una lista de elementos de la entidad.

¿Saben que podria estar pasando?

Comment: Hola, por favor agrega el còdigo como texto no como imagen por favor, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Las clases que terminan con `_` son *JPA metamodel classes* que deberían ser generadas automáticamente. El error que muestras puede ser porque la clase no fue generada o bien porque fue generada en una carpeta que no forma parte del sourceset del proyecto. En cualquier caso puedes solucionarlo agregando el siguiente snippet en tu archivo pom.xml dentro de la etiqueta `plugin` que tenga el id `kotlin-maven-plugin`

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>kapt</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>kapt</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <sourceDirs>
                <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
            </sourceDirs>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <annotationProcessorPath>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                    <version>5.5.7.Final</version>
                </annotationProcessorPath>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Para explicarlo brevemente, esto activa el [Hibernate Metamodel Generator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/topical/html_single/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html), el plugin kapt (pulgin del compilador de kotlin necesario para ejecutar *annotation processors*) y configura el sourceDirectory.

Pero ten en cuenta que usar metamodels es sólo una recomendación, no es estrictamente necesario. Siempre puedes usar strings como venías haciendo en las líneas anteriores

```
entity.get("Providers")
```

Recuerda que esto no tiene que ver con el método `isMember`. Si vas a usar metamodels hazlo en todos los predicados. Ejemplo:

```
builder.equal(entity.get(Content_.ReleaseYear), releaseYear)
```